# Find people who have all three cards

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

In Excel I have the following cells for 1,000s data. For example:

```
Index,   cardNo,  Name  
1.       110-1    Chris  
2.       130-210  David  
3.       110-1    Sex  
4.       120-111  Difficult  
and so on..
```

As you can see cardNo has three values : `110-1`, `130-210`, `120-111`. I need to find people who have all three cards.

How should I script it?

Comment: No, it is not working unfortunately.. all it give is False..

Comment: I have checked some manually, it indeed have people with all three cards. Afterall there are 1000s of people so I expect a lot. I am using 2010

Comment: Ok got it!
 =AND(IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, "110-1", C:C, C2), True, False), IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, "130-210", C:C, C2), True, False), IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, "120-111", C:C, C2), True, False)). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it!

> =AND(IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, "110-1", C:C, C2), True, False), IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, "130-210", C:C, C2), True, False), IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, "120-111", C:C, C2), True, False)).

Thanks a lot!